# Update Oracle table column with row number

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, oracle10g

I want to update a table column with row number. 
Each row in `empid` column should update with related row number.
I tried following query.

```
UPDATE employee SET empid = row_number();
```

But this is not working. Any idea?

Comment: It is syntactically incorrect. You can't use `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function like that. You need to show us the desired output with an example. Does order matter here?

Comment: Order does not matter

Comment: Then simply use `ROWNUM`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, this is not the correct syntax for the `row_number()` function, since you're missing the `over` clause (resulting in an ORA-30484 error). Even if it was, this would not work, as you cannot directly use window functions in a `set` clause (resulting in an ORA-30483 error).

For this usecase, however, you could just use the `rownum` pseudo-column:

```
UPDATE employee SET empid = ROWNUM;
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ac08f/1/0)**

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like the following. You can change the ORDER BY order the rows if needed.

```
UPDATE emp
SET empid = emp.RowNum
FROM (SELECT empid, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY empid) AS rowNum FROM employee) emp
```

Answer (score 0):

> UPDATE employee SET empid = row_number();

Firstly, it is syntactically incorrect.

Secondly, you cannot use `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function without the **analytic_clause**.

As you replied to my comment that the order doesn't matter to you, you could simply use **ROWNUM**.

```
UPDATE employee SET empid = ROWNUM;
```

It will assign the pseudo-column value by randomly picking the rows. Since you are assigning **EMPID**, I would suggest you should consider ordering.

Usually employee ids are generated using a **SEQUENCE** object. There are two ways to implement the auto-increment functionality:

- **Oracle 11g and below** - [**Auto-increment using trigger-sequence approach**](http://lalitkumarb.com/2015/01/20/auto-increment-primary-key-in-pre-12c-releases-identity-functionality/)
- **Oracle 12c** - [**IDENTITY column autoincrement functionality**](http://lalitkumarb.com/2015/01/20/identity-column-autoincrement-functionality-in-oracle-12c/)

Answer (score 0):

you could also do this

```
create table your_table_name as
select row_number() over( order by 1) as serial_no, a.* from your_query a
```

this creates the serial number when you write the table itself. ( note this is not set as PK if you want it to act as pk)